# Moving multiple specific folders on windows

Tags: python, r, windows, powershell, move

I have a list of multiple specific directories that I would like to move to another folder on Windows.
The list is stored in a txt.file which contains the paths of these directories:

```
"C:/Path/to/my/folder1/"
"C:/Path/to/my/folder4/"
"C:/Path/to/my/folder9/"
```

I would like to move all these folders including there subfolders to a new directory:

```
C:/Path/to/new/directory/
```

Is there a smart way to do this by powershell, python or R on windows?

**Edit** (Sorry, didn't include my first attempts initially):

I had previously tried using the "`file.copy(list_of_paths, target_path`)" command in R, but it always returned "FALSE FALSE". If I understood correctly, it seems that R on windows has difficulties handling folders rather than files (I'm used to unix and haven't come across that issue before).

The other thing I tried was using the Copy-Item command on Powershell (`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Path\of\files' -Recurse| Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Path\to\target'`), but I'm not sure how to load a list of paths in Powershell.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Questions which do not show any research effort or are not specific to a particular language and show no code are normally downvoted or closed.

Comment: Sorry for that, my bad! I have added my initial attempts in the edited post.

Comment: `"Path1","Path2","Path3" | Move-Item -Destination "C:/Path/to/new/directory/"`. Should be all you really need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using R. Assuming that your filepaths are stored in a list `fpath`:

```
file.copy(fpath, "C:/Path/to/new/directory/")
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem I have had in R is that whenever I try to copy a folder incl. subfolders with file.copy, I get the return "FALSE". The command only seems to work for files rather than folders if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I used your suggestion with recursive=T and it worked perfectly now, thanks so much! file.copy(fpath, "C:/Path/to/new/directory", recursive=T)

Answer (score 0):

## Alternate Solution(s)

The previous answer provides a solution in `R` for *copying* recursively the folders from source to target.

Per your question, you need to *move* the folders and maintain their relative sub-folder structure from the root path.

---

I know that's not a big deal because you can simply copy recursively over the folders and delete originals, however, in general moving is much faster than copying and it's what you asked for so here's what I've got.

---

I propose the following solutions:

### PowerShell Solution

The simplest solution is to simply run:

```
# showing different ways of specifying paths
$fromDirs = @( 
    ".\folder1"
    "C:\Path\to\my\folder2\"
    "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\TestDir"
)

$destDir = "$HOME\Desktop\"

ForEach ($dir in $fromDirs) {
    Move-Item -Path $dir -Destination $destDir -Force
}
```

Another, more involved PowerShell solution is as follows:

```
$fromDirs = @(
    "C:\Path\to\my\folder1"
    "C:\Path\to\my\folder2\"
    "C:\Path\to\my\folder3\"
)

$toDir = "C:\Path\to\my\destination\"

$fromDirs | ForEach-Object {
    $fromDir = $_
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $fromDir -Recurse -File
    $Files | ForEach-Object {
        $File = $_
        $RelativePath = $File.FullName.Replace($fromDir, '')
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $toDir -ChildPath $RelativePath
        $DestinationDir = Split-Path -Path $Destination -Parent
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $DestinationDir)) {
            New-Item -Path $DestinationDir -ItemType Directory -Force
        }
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
    }
}
```

this more advanced solution deals with the relativistic hierarchy issues when moving recursive paths.

#### Relative Folder Hierarchy

In order to maintain *relative* path consistency (i.e. when moving the folders and subfolders, you will need to create the relative path structure first before moving/copying the files over), a little more advanced solution is necessary than simply running `Move-Item -Path $fromDir -Destination $toDir -Force` since the `Move-Item` cmdlet does not support recursion (and it shouldn't for various reasons).

### R Solution

In R, I would go with [`fs::dir_copy()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/copy.html) over base R (a practice I usually avoid) due to its file system management practices in Windows and its `dir_copy()` function being more robust than base R `file.copy()` in this scenario.

```
require(fs)
fs::dir_copy(c("folder1", "folder2"), "DestinationFolder")
```

But to address the topic of *moving* instead of *copying* the best solution in R is to use base R's `file.rename()` function.

```
# this moves a directory from one location to another:
file.rename(folder_old_path, path_new)
```

for multiple directories with subdirectories:

```
to <- "todir"
froms <- c("dir1", "dir2")
tos <- paste0(to, "/", froms)

file.rename(froms, tos)
```

will result in "dir1" and "dir2" moving to "todir/dir1/*" and "todir/dir2/*".

Note that if "todir" doesn't exist you will need to check that first via `if (dir.exists(to)) { ... }`

---

### Copying vs. Moving

Just like on UNIX, copying is used to copy from one place to another while moving is used to move a file or folder. Moving will not have a flag for recursion (i.e. no `-r` flag) because it will automatically move all sub-folders and files to the specified destination's path. Copying, however, allows you to specify the recursion option to copy directories recursively. Lastly, be wary of overwriting pre-existing files in the destination path.

Also, if you are on Windows you should use the correct path separators (`\` instead of `/`; or to be safe just go with double `\\`).